# Is this lengthy pseudo class combination a valid statement?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-class

**This is my code:**

```css
.fontmenu .fontlist{
        position: absolute;
        bottom:30px;
        display:none;

    }

.fontbutton button:hover .fontmenu .fontlist{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="fontmenu">
    <div class="fontbutton">
        <button>fonts</button>
    </div>
    <div class="fontlist">  
        <div onclick="font(1)">Arial</div>
        <div onclick="font(2)">Courier</div>
        <div onclick="font(3)">Verdana</div>
        <div onclick="font(4)">sans</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is not working. The list is not visible when I hover the button. I want to know whether the `.fontbutton button:hover .fontmenu .fontlist{}` is valid or not.

Comment: It is valid yes, but what is your HTML and what are you trying to achive?

Comment: Yes, this is correct! Look it - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html

Comment: You need to use sibling selector `+` if the elements are at the same level.

Comment: We can't help unless you show us what you're targeting. Post all the relevant information, please.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have used:

```css
.fontbutton button:hover .fontmenu .fontlist{ }
```

#### This won't work

Why it won't work? Read on. I will explain. But first, lets see what will work.

---

Lets try using some selectors:

```css
.fontbutton:hover + .fontlist {}
```

**This WILL work**

Let's see it in action:

```css
.fontmenu .fontlist {
  bottom: 30px;
  display: none;
}

.fontbutton:hover + .fontlist {
  display: block;
}


/* No need to include the wrapper fontmenu div,
just target the siblings, ie, fontbutton and fontlist.
The + selector must be used, otherwise, the browser will
think fontlist is the child of fontbutton */
```

```html
<div class="fontmenu">
  <div class="fontbutton">
    <button>fonts</button>
  </div>
  <div class="fontlist">
    <div onclick="font(1)">Arial</div>
    <div onclick="font(2)">Courier</div>
    <div onclick="font(3)">Verdana</div>
    <div onclick="font(4)">sans</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Notice that the list becomes visible even if we hover to the *right* of the button.** This is happening since we are targeting the div `fontbutton` and not the `<button>` element. So, the browser makes the list visible when we hover the div and not the button.

#### How to fix?

We need to change the html a little.

```css
.fontmenu .fontlist {
  display: none;
}

button:hover + .fontlist {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fontmenu">
  <button>fonts</button>
  <div class="fontlist">
    <div onclick="font(1)">Arial</div>
    <div onclick="font(2)">Courier</div>
    <div onclick="font(3)">Verdana</div>
    <div onclick="font(4)">sans</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Look that I removed the `.fontbutton` class and made the `<button>` a sibling of `.fontlist`. So, now, you can see that the list is visible only when we hover the button.

---

**Now you would say I could just add some selectors to your css.** But I didn't because there's no way you could target `<button>` and then move down to `.fontlist` which is in a **separate** div.

```css
.fontbutton > button:hover ? .fontmenu > .fontlist{ }
```

We will have a problem at the place of `?`.

1. First, we need to go down to `.button`.
2. Move up to `.fontbutton`.
3. Add a `+` selector and switch to `.fontmenu`.
4. Move down to `.fontlist`.

After we move down to `.button`, we can't go up again to `.fontbutton`.

### CSS doesn't have something like parent selector.

So, clearly, we can't use it that way.

Comment: button is not a class in my case.Its a tag

Comment: @BlenderExplorer Look I have changed the answer. This should solve your problem. Any more queries, just comment here and  I would be happy to help you. Have a Good Day!

Comment: ok.Thanks..My understanding of css was wrong..   I was thinking that  ".fontbutton button:hover .fontmenu .fontlist" meansthat  if(.fontbutton button:hover) then{.fontmenu .fontlist} ..Now I understood that  its if(.fontbutton button:hover)then{.fontbutton button .fontmenu .fontlist}

Comment: @Explorador Noo. You are wrong again. It actually means that if `button` inside `.fontbutton` is hovered, then add these css rules to `.fontlist` inside `.fontmenu`.